# How to use OpenSeaDragon with Virutal Slide

Tags: openseadragon, openslide

I am new to openseadragon and would like to create a webbased viewer from some Aperio .svs while slide images.  I am using c# and .net and have openslide creating thumbnails, barcode images, etc.  But I am stuck on how do to get openseadragon to display the svs file.  I see you can convert the svs to dzi but am not sure how to deliver the image to openseadragon.  Do you use a webservice and do it tile by tile or can you simply output the entire image in dzi format to openseadragon?  I am totally lost on what openseadragon needs to see from a virutal slide.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSeadragon supports a variety of tile sources, but all of them are based on formats the browser understands, like JPEG. I'm not familiar with SVS, but presumably it's not something the browser understands natively; thus the conversion step.

Anyway, yes, if you convert to a DZI, you can just put that DZI on your server as static files (it's a folder full of files), and then point OpenSeadragon to it on your webpage, like so:

```
<div id="openseadragon1" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
<script src="/openseadragon/openseadragon.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
        id: "openseadragon1",
        prefixUrl: "/openseadragon/images/",
        tileSources: "/path/to/my/image.dzi"
    });
</script>
```

That should be enough, assuming you have all of the paths set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

OSD cannot understand SVS files because SVS files are essentially not "web-friendly".
We provide an image server to do exactly this, but it's commercial and may not be what you hope for. Here's an example however:

```
https://he.tissuetek.cloud
```

These are native SVS files being served into OSD.

As mentioned above, an alternative would be to convert your files into DZI. Bear in mind that instead of one file, you will now have tens of thousands, even millions, of files to manage.